# Use @ActiveProfiles together with SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, continuous-integration

In my Spring Boot application I have tree profiles: the default profile, a test profile and a continuous integration profile.

The continuous integration profile define an alternative datasource.url.

The test profile define an alternative liquibase.change-log.

The default profile define default properties for my application.

When I run tests locally I run them using IntellIJ

[image]

and to active the test profile locally I have added the `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation to my tests.

and when I run them from my CI I have add the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env var like this:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=ci,test gradle integrationTest
```

but the ci profile is ignored by Spring Boot.

If I remove the `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation my CI work perfectly but then I can not easily run my tests using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

When you add `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to your test class, you are overriding the active profiles definition set by the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env var.

1. One option would be to add the "ci" profile to the test class execution:

   ```
    @ActiveProfiles({"test", "ci"})
   ```
2. If activating "ci" for local/IDE test execution is not desirable, another option would be to remove the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation, and use `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` in your IDE run configuration for your test.
3. But if you want profile "test" active on all tests, you could simply remove the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation, remove "test" from your env var CI job definition, and add the following line to application.properties/yaml inside the *test/resources* folder. (If you don't have test/resources/application.properties yet, know that it overrides main/resources/application.properties.)

   ```
    spring.profiles.include = test
   ```